# Can i get deleted network policies on namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, history, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I need to find out the history of network policies on a namespace.
`kubectl get networkpolicy` shows only available ones.

Is there any command that I can see deleted network policies?

Comment: No, by default, you cannot get the back. That's why you should source control everything you do. Additionally, some people use cluster backup tools such as velero.

Comment: Actually, we do. Some people still use oc commands to update and we can't prevent it. I believe we should be more careful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not limited to `network policies`. In the Kubernetes cluster, if you want to see the logs for any resource creation, update, or deletion, you can find them in the `audit logs`. You can read more about audit logs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/).

**Note/Limitations**:

1. Audit logs are already enabled in most real clusters after creation. However, for many test(`hello world`) clusters, you need to enable them.
2. Not all users have access to view the audit logs.
3. If the audit logs aren't enabled for a resource type(in your case, network policy), you cannot obtain the details.
4. Like any other logs, `audit` logs also rotate, so if you are trying to find details of some event that happened way back then, the logs will be lost due to rotation.